# Check for a repeating sequence in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe, a column of which has a repeating sequence of values which almost looks like the following:

```
      Cell
0      x_a
1      x_b
2      x_c
3      x_a
4      x_b
5      x_c
6      x_a
7      x_b
8      x_b
9      x_c
10     x_c
11     x_b
12     x_a
```

I need to check through this entire column to see that the repetition of this sequence "x_a, x_b, x_c" is exactly maintained in this order, i.e. "x_c" follows x_b" follows "x_a".

Wherever this order is broken, e.g. in indices 7 and 8 where "B" is repeated twice or 10, 11, 12 where the order is wrong, I need to be able to find out which value is playing foul?

Any pointers on how to do it?

I've been scratching my head with `df.loc` all this while but to no avail and I'm fairly certain `df.loc` is not the right way.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What are the rules for determining what the correct order should be? In other words are the only types of errors repeats and reversals?

Comment: Can you check the answer if it solves the problem?

Comment: @Alex: There is only one rule: "x_c" should follow x_b". And "x_b" should follow "x_a". And then the sequence is repeated. It's like 123, 123, 123 and so on.. Anything that violates that order, i.e. repetition of a value or reversal is incorrect.

Comment: @Bhushan: Thanks a lot. It worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this solution with a pre-defined rule for the order:

```
import pandas as pd

#Creating Dummy Dataframe
dummy_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=["dummy"])

#Adding Dummy Values to the DataFrame
dummy_frame["dummy"] = ["x_a","x_b","x_c","x_a","x_b","x_c","x_a","x_a","x_b"]

#Pre-defining order to check in the dataframe
correct_order = ["x_a","x_b","x_c"]

#For Loop Based on length of the order (Triplets in this case)
for i in range(0,len(dummy_frame),len(correct_order)):

    #Check if the order is matched
    if correct_order != dummy_frame["dummy"][i:i+3].tolist():
        for j in range(len(correct_order)):

            #Check for the incorrect value in the triplet
            if correct_order[j] != dummy_frame["dummy"][i:i+3].tolist()[j]:
                print "Value at index:",i+j,"is incorrect."
                print "Current Value:",dummy_frame["dummy"][i:i+3].tolist()[j],"Correct Value is:",correct_order[j]
```

Sample Output:

```
Value at index: 7 is incorrect.
Current Value: x_a Correct Value is: x_b
Value at index: 8 is incorrect.
Current Value: x_b Correct Value is: x_c
```

Hope this helps :)